# Is there a way to query MongoDB collection with an embedded array to return the element's offset within the array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, offset

Given the following documents in the school collection:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    zipcode: "63109",
    students: [
        { name: "john", school: 102, age: 10 },
        { name: "jess", school: 102, age: 11 },
        { name: "jeff", school: 108, age: 15 }
    ]
}
{
    _id: 2,
    zipcode: "63110",
    students: [
        { name: "ajax", school: 100, age: 7 },
        { name: "achilles", school: 100, age: 8 },
    ]
}
{
    _id: 3,
    zipcode: "63109",
    students: [
        { name: "ajax", school: 100, age: 7 },
        { name: "achilles", school: 100, age: 8 },
    ]
}
{
    _id: 4,
    zipcode: "63109",
    students: [
        { name: "barney", school: 102, age: 7 },
        { name: "ruth", school: 102, age: 16 },
    ]
}
```

Here is the example query in MongoDB docs:

```
db.schools.find( { zipcode: "63109" },
             { students: { $elemMatch: { school: 108 } } } )
```

It will return a result like this:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "students" : [ { "name" : "jeff", "school" : 108, "age" : 15 } ] }
```

My question is how to get a result like this:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "students" : [ { "name" : "jeff", "school" : 108, "age" : 15, "offset" : 2 } ] }
```

As you can see, this result adds a field offset. Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: Arrays are fixed in position, so `0` is the first element and `1` is the second element. You don't need additional information in the document to tell you the position.

Comment: I know it's fixed, but I wish it's included in the result so I don't need to count it. Actually I'm going to use '$elemMatch' together with '$projection'.

Comment: The original example was sort of misleading, I've updated it.

Comment: Could I suggest here before providing any other input, to what end do you "think" you need to know the document index? It seems likely that the reason you "think" you need it does not actually apply and there would be another way to solve the problem you think you are solving. There are ways, but none of them are smart.

Comment: OK, that'll really need some explanation. Actually I'm designing a ranking list. The documents being sorted don't change. Of course I can do a `count` to get someone's ranking. But since the ranking doesn't change, I think I can save the ranking list in another collection as a document with an embedded array. But in this case, how can I get someone's ranking? I know it's exactly the offset within the array. But the way of reading the entire embedded array out is kinda ugly. I'm here to seek an elegant way.

Comment: Basics. 1. "Projection" standard does not "alter" document output to things that are not there. 2. Aggregation framework and mapReduce are the only server side operations that can alter the output from the original document. 3. The aggregation framework cannot "efficiently" assign an "offset" to an array position. 4. Any "slicing" with calculated positions would need to be done "after" all the positions were calculated. Which leads to 5. Given all the above, it makes more sense to "store" and "update" your ranking in the document than calculate it "on the fly"

Comment: Also see how your "real question" here differs extremely from the question you originally asked.

Comment: Yes, the "real question" is kinda complicated, I just tried to simplify it. So the solution is doing a `aggregation` to get a sorted ranking list, iterating it to add a `ranking` field and then storing it in a document as an embedded array. After that, if I need someone's ranking, I `query` this document using `$elemMatch` operator. Is it?

Comment: I would keep the data personally, even if it meant regular updates. Overall it's a lot cleaner than trying to get this dynamically, and the performance cost of running updates outstrips the cost incurred trying to calculate at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work around for your problem :

```
 db.schools.find( { zipcode: "63109" },
    { _id : 1 , students : 1 }).forEach( function(doc){
   var arr = doc.students;
   for( var index = 0 ; index < arr.length ; index++ )
     {
        if( arr[index].school == 108 )
         {
        var d = arr[index];
        d["offset"] = index;
         }
         else
         {
        arr.splice(index, 1);

         }
      }
    });
```